# how to find the version of a service using chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, version

I need to find the version number so that if it does not match the latest then I need to upload it .

```
service 'McAfeeFramework' do 
supports :status => true
action  :start
log.version_number
end
```

Comment: That's package responsibility to handle version, not service, a service is just a program running in background. You should really go through https://learn.chef.io and follow the tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

So programs, assemblies, and the like have versions, to the best of my knowledge services do not. Unless there is some metadata I'm unaware, what you are asking is not a thing.